# How Can My Browser's Flash Version Get Outdated in 10 Mins?

Tags: firefox, browser, flash, flash-player

I visited a site (http://gaana.com) for the first time today. I chose an album and started the playlist. I listened to about 2 songs and then suddenly the audio player stopped abruptly.

I tried clicking the Play/Pause button but that didn't seem to do anything. Finally, I did a page refresh and got the following message:
[image: Flash Error]

So what could possibly have happened in 10 minutes? I checked for a Firefox update but the browser is up to date:
[image]

I'm using an office PC so could it possible that the IT Dept found out about the streaming and somehow disabled Flash in my browser? Is that even possible?

What are my options in that case? Any way I could bypass this Flash check?

PS: I get the same error message in Google Chrome too and that browser is up to date too.

Comment: When installing flash, never click the link on a webpage that says your flash needs to be upgraded, always take that as a hint to go to Adobe.com and use the tools there to check or upgrade.   I don't know anything about the site you mention, but "oops your flash isn't the latest" is a good way to get you to install malware.

Comment: Comment above really is an an *Answer*. As @Tyson states, don't trust the link, which *seems* to be to Adobe, but get the actual Flash plugin from adobe.com.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser and Flash are different. Firefox is the browsing software (browser) and Flash is a plugin (additional software) that is used by Firefox. Firefox may be up to date, but Adobe Flash out of date at the same time.

As the comments above suggest, goto https://get.adobe.com/ or use Firefox's internal plugin updating function.